# What does a '&' stand for in a python bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

What does an ampersand `&` mean at the end of a python `bytearray`?

e.g.:

```
x_w = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x04\x12\xaa\x12\x12&')
```

When converting this to an integer by

```
int.from_bytes(x_w, 'little')

Out[1]: 2743275644678045696
```

it gives a different result from the same bytearray without the '&':

```
x_wo = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x04\x12\xaa\x12\x12')
int.from_bytes(x_wo, 'little')

Out[2]: 5087071236784128
```

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) but haven't found an answer to this. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a character. Change to big endian and you get `0x‭412AA121226‬` and `0x26` is char code for `&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply the representation of the byte with value `26` (decimal 38), which is the `'&'` character in ASCII.

If you print the actual byte values of the bytes literal you used, you can see this clearly:

```
>>> print(' '.join('%02x' % b for b in b'\x00\x00\x04\x12\xaa\x12\x12&'))
00 00 04 12 aa 12 12 26
```

And the `repr` of the `bytearray` object prefers to represent bytes using ASCII characters rather than hex escapes whenever possible. So it will prefer the representation `'&'` rather than `'\x26'`, even though they are technically equivalent:

```
>>> bytearray([0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x12, 0xAA, 0x12, 0x12, 0x26])
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x04\x12\xaa\x12\x12&')

>>> b'\x26' == b'&'
True
```